# One-to-one and onto

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this is a fairly easy question, but I want to ask anyway, since I don't know if I remember all correctly.

Suppose a linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ has the property that $T(\mathbf{u}) = T(\mathbf{v})$ for some pair of distinct vectors $\bf{u}$ and $\bf{v}$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Can $T$ map $\Bbb R^n$ onto $\Bbb R^n$? Why or why not?

What I think, is that because of the distinct vectors in $T(\mathbf{u}) = T(\mathbf{v})$, $T$ is not one-to-one, and then because of the Invertible Matrix Theorem it cannot map $\Bbb R^n$ onto $\Bbb R^n$. Is this that simple? It's been a year since I took the previous course in linear algebra...

Comment: You're exactly right. The way to think about it is that $T(u-v) = 0$ so $T$ has nontrivial nullspace which in turn says it's not invertible which in turn says it is not one-to-one or onto.

Comment: @Cameron Just to be crystal clear, it should be noted that a transformation with nontrivial nullspace is *never* one-to-one; in this case it is also not onto since the dimensions of domain and range are equal.

Comment: @rogerl Quite right. I guess I should have been a little bit clearer there. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I found the dimension theorem very helpful $\mbox{dim} V = \mbox{dim} \, \mbox{ker} \, \varphi + \mbox{dim} \, \mbox{rg} \varphi$ to understand what is going on for a linear map $\varphi$.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I don't know everything you talk about here (yet), but now I know that my reasoning was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remember this theorem (rank-nullity): $$\dim \Bbb R^n = \dim \mathrm{ker}~ T + \dim \mathrm{Im}~T $$
where $\mathrm{ker}~T = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \Bbb R^n : T(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0} \}$. Another theorem states that $T$ is one-to-one if and only if $\mathrm{ker} ~T = \{0\}$. 
If $T(\mathbf{u}) =$ $T(\mathbf{v})$, clearly $T$ isn't one-to-one, but to remember better, you can think that $T(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}) = 0$, hence $\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v} \in \mathrm{ker}~T \neq \{0\}$ and from this, $T$ can't be one-to-one. And $\dim \mathrm{Im}~T \geq 1$, so from the first expression, $\dim \mathrm{Im}~T < n$, so $T$ also can't be onto.

Comment: Thanks! This is more "formal" than what I wrote. Which is good, I think. :-)